# Box2d debug render

Tags: box2d, andengine

How can I render the body and joints in the physics world? During research I found the class called Box2dDebugRenderer. But when I put it into use it was full of errors. I do not found some classed in it. My basic requirement is to draw a body that were available in the physics world. Please provide some guidance on that. Also provide any other view about that.

Answer (score 2):

With my limited experience with physics engines, the developer is required to implement their own drawing code for that the physics engine then uses for debug drawing.

It's usually broken down into simple methods for you to implement like `line(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY)`, where you need to implement the functionality to draw the line specified. This might be the reason for it being "full of errors", but without more information it's hard to tell.

You can take a look at libgdx to see how it's [been implemented](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Box2DDebugRenderer.java) there. And look into the `ShapeRenderer` they [employ here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html).

Comment: No need to reimplement this, it was done three times now and using it is as simple as mScene.attachChild(new Box2dDebugRenderer(mPhysicsWorld));

Comment: Thanks @JohnEye I should probably let you answer first from here on :)

Answer (score 2):

What version of AndEngine are you using? GLES1 or GLES2? It is likely that you are trying to use an outdated version.

If GLES1, the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/andenginephysicsbox2ddebugrenderer/) works just fine. I linked it to my GLES1 project today.

I you use GLES2, there is a thread about it over at the [AndEngine forums](http://www.andengine.org/forums/post29371.html#p29371).

Please note that using this will make your app run quite slow.

Comment: I did not found any thing useful to me. The downloaded extension contains an error and anything does not found in the bin folder except res folder

Comment: Again, you need to specify the version of AndEngine you use.

Comment: I downloaded the lastest andEngine version from the site but when I import the project it also contains an error and the bin folder was empty without any jar file.

Comment: I was using andengine version GLES1

Comment: Then it should work. What error do you see?

Comment: My andengine extension does not contain box2ddebugrenderer class but when I manually add it into my package it contains error for class ShapeRenderer,Matrix4, EdgeShape, ChainShape class not found. Provide guidance for what I do further.

Comment: OK. Let's do it from the beginning. First, in Eclipse open the Import dialog, choose "Project from SVN", then choose "Create a new repository location". On the next screen, place the following address as an URL: http://andenginephysicsbox2ddebugrenderer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk and click next. Eclipse may complain, if it does, select "No". You should now be on the "Select resource" screen. The URL should be the same as before, with "trunk" at the end. Click Finish. New window ("Check Out As") will pop up. The project name should be filled in and the last option selected (continued)

Comment: (continued) Check out as a project with the name specified. Eclipse should automatically select this option and fill in the name for you. Click Finish and you should now have the project in your workplace. Then right click your own project, select Properties and go to the Android screen. On the lower right side there is a Library part, click Add, select the debug renderer project and click OK. It should now appear among the other Libraries (if there weren't any, your AndEngine is not configured properly) with a green tick next to it. That means that the projects are linked. (continued)

Comment: Then just add this line to your game activity and you are done. [your scene variable].attachChild(new Box2dDebugRenderer([your physics world variable]));